# Failed to connect to Load Balancer while performing transactions between Corda nodes using AWS Corda Enterprise template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, blockchain, corda

1. I am evaluating AWS Corda Enterprise template.
2. I have two Corda Enterprise nodes (PartyA and PartyB) connected to Corda Testnet. Both the nodes are under same subnet having different security group.
3. To test the installation of Corda Enterprise node on Corda Testnet, I am refering this document [https://docs.corda.r3.com/testnet-explorer.html]
4. After performing issuance transaction using Node explorer between the 2 parties, I am not able to make the transaction successful.
5. AMPQ Client is failing to connect to Load Balancer at port 10002 by giving following error:

```
[INFO ] 2019-02-26T09:08:46,926Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-1] netty.AMQPClient.operationComplete - Failed to connect to Corda-Par-P2PLoadB-xxxxx-301305085.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com:10002 {}
[ERROR] 2019-02-26T09:09:01,415Z [Thread-2 (ActiveMQ-scheduled-threads)] core.server.lambda$channelActive$0 - AMQ224088: Timeout (10 seconds) while handshaking has occurred. {}
[ERROR] 2019-02-26T09:09:12,632Z [Thread-3 (ActiveMQ-scheduled-threads)] core.server.lambda$channelActive$0 - AMQ224088: Timeout (10 seconds) while handshaking has occurred. {}
[INFO ] 2019-02-26T09:09:12,989Z [pool-14-thread-1] statemachine.FlowMonitor.logFlowsWaitingForParty - Flow with id xxxxx has been waiting for 74276 seconds to receive messages from parties [O=xxxx, L=xxxx, C=IN]. {}
[ERROR] 2019-02-26T09:09:31,415Z [Thread-0 (ActiveMQ-scheduled-threads)] core.server.lambda$channelActive$0 - AMQ224088: Timeout (10 seconds) while handshaking has occurred. {}
[ERROR] 2019-02-26T09:09:42,632Z [Thread-2 (ActiveMQ-scheduled-threads)] core.server.lambda$channelActive$0 - AMQ224088: Timeout (10 seconds) while handshaking has occurred. {}
[INFO ] 2019-02-26T09:09:46,986Z [nioEventLoopGroup-2-2] netty.AMQPClient.nextTarget - Retry connect to Corda-Par-P2PLoadB-xxxxx-301305085.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com:10002 {}
[ERROR] 2019-02-26T09:10:01,414Z [Thread-0 (ActiveMQ-scheduled-threads)] core.server.lambda$channelActive$0 - AMQ224088: Timeout (10 seconds) while handshaking has occurred. {}
[ERROR] 2019-02-26T09:10:12,632Z [Thread-1 (ActiveMQ-scheduled-threads)] core.server.lambda$channelActive$0 - AMQ224088: Timeout (10 seconds) while handshaking has occurred. {}
[INFO ] 2019-02-26T09:10:12,989Z [pool-14-thread-1] statemachine.FlowMonitor.logFlowsWaitingForParty - Flow with id xxxxx has been waiting for 74336 seconds to receive messages from parties [O=xxxx, L=xxxx, C=IN]. {}
```

In the Inbound rules of security group of both the parties, TCP port is enabled to port 10002.

Can anyone please help me to solve my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the error by adding the inbound rule to each security group of both the parties as All traffic to 0.0.0.0/0